# How do I overwrite back button of BSImagePicker gallery?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new new in Java and working on an old project that uses [bsImagePicker](https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker). There's a bug in my current project that when the user wants to click the below back button of the gallery it takes the user to home page.

[image]

This shouldn't be the default behavior, rather it should take the user 1 step back. Please, How do I overwrite the method of this back button? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any xml file that has referenced this button neither there's any previous overwritten method.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I searched more and figured out maybe it has to do something with `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` but I don't know how to set its `android:parentActivityName` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To override `onBackPressed()` method and implement your own functionality or behavior.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       //implement your own functionality in this
}
```

But since you are trying to implement it for back button shown in attached image and you don't have reference of it. Either you can create a reference by own or you can try on `onCancelled` method as provided in BSImagePicker gallary github repo.

```
//Optional
@Override
public void onCancelled(boolean isMultiSelecting, String tag) {
    //Do whatever you want when user cancelled
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit, I added it in https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/asksira/imagepickersheetdemo/MainActivity.java , but it doesn't overwrite anything.

Comment: did you tried ```onCancelled()``` method?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that method fires when user cancel selecting images. Please clone above repository and implement to see if it's possible.

Comment: Try customizing xml layout https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker#customize-layout-of-camera-tile-or-gallery-tile

Comment: I cloned the project and check all resources files including XML files, but there I couldn't find that back arrow and top header text. Basically everything is there except this top header.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how do I create a reference on my own?

Comment: I think the image you are referring is not even from BSImagePicker but its default Image Pick option. If you are still facing issue try raising an issue about it on their github repo.